# How can I call a method in the AppShell class of a Xamarin app that I have a reference to?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
public partial class App : Application {
    public App() {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}

public partial class AppShell : Shell {
    public void abc() {
        Shell.SetTabBarForegroundColor(this, Color.Red);
        Shell.SetTabBarTitleColor(this, Color.Blue);
        Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false);
    }
    public AppShell() { }
}
```

Inside the app code I can access the Application MainPage like this but I cannot call the method that I placed there:

```
var a = Application.Current.MainPage;
a.abc() << Doesn't work
```

Comment: public void abc() ==> public static void abc(); then call  it AppShell.abc();

Comment: probably the type of Application.Current.Mainpage is not AppShell. Then you can / have to cast it to that type. Try ((AppShell)Application.Current.MainPage).abc()

Comment: @david - Did you mean to have three == .  I have never seen anything like that before but hope it's something I can use.

Comment: no, ==> means "replace with"

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HMyEbI Please see if this link is clearer to you.

Comment: @Alan2 Check my answer it should work for you!

Comment: What Thomas Voß said is right, cast the type of MainPage to  AppShell  will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the `Shell.Current` property then cast it to your type of custom shell and call the method you wanna call

```
var AppShellInstance= Xamarin.Forms.Shell.Current as AppShell;
AppShellInstance.abc();
```

Answer (score 1):

AppShell MainPage; this should **NOT** be declared in constructor, but a class variable/field.

```
using System;

public class Program
{   

    public class App {      
        public static AppShell MainPage; //Put this outside constructor
        static App () {
            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
    }


    public class AppShell   {
        public void abc() {
            Console.WriteLine("AppShell::abc");
        }
        public AppShell() { }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        App.MainPage.abc();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Application.Current.MainPage is AppShell a) {
    a.abc();
}
```

Comment: first it check if `Application.Current.MainPage` is **not null** and cast to `AppShell` into variable `a`, if `MainPage` is **null** it will goto `else` statement